# Thread-safe access to static collection

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety

I am creating a class that will have a Key-Value pairing of some sort. Currently, I have something similar to the following:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> PropertyCache { get; set; }
```

Is this the correct way of implementing in a thread-safe approach? For some reason there is something nagging me about the effect of `static` on the `Dictionary` in this case. If this is correct, is there an incorrect way that can be demonstrated so that I can avoid it in the rest of my code.

Also, should it be read-only (I am only ever going to add-remove things from the collection)?

If it makes a difference, the property will always be declared `private`.

Thanks in advance

*Although tagged C#, answers in VB are ok, I am "Bi-lingual" so to speak*

**EDIT:**

Following discussion with Jon Skeet in the comments of his answer, the usage will be:

```
// I will do this
PropertyCache.Add(typeof(string), new List<PropertyInfo>());
PropertyCache.Remove(typeof(string));

// I will never do this 
PropertyCache = new Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>>();
```

I will never iterate over the collection either, only access by key.

Comment: What does "I am only ever going to add-remove things from the collection" mean?

Comment: @SteveDanner, eg I am never going to go `PropertyCache = new Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>>` only `PropertyCache.Add(item)` :)

Comment: OK, a ReadOnlyDictionary won't work then.  Consider Jon Skeet's answer, IMO.

Comment: You ask: "Is this the correct way of implementing in a thread-safe approach?" The answer to that is a resounding "No." Marking something static has nothing to do with thread safety. It merely marks an object as shared between object instances. Shared. All instances have access to that same object. The object itself (or the code trying to access it) will have to implement thread-safe logic on access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a member `static` makes it more likely to have cross-thread access than an instance member. Remember that `static` doesn't mean something is safe for use by multiple threads, it means the object is shared between multiple instances of an object in which it is defined.

Collections which implement the `ICollection` interface can be cast to access a `SyncRoot` you can use to `lock` an object to ensure only one thread at a time can execute a series of instructions that would cause the collection to change. [Using SyncRoot for Multithreaded Applications](http://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/using-syncroot-for-multithreaded-applications/)

```
lock(((ICollection)myObject).SyncRoot)
{
    //Code that should be executed by only one concurrent thread
    //This is add/insert/remove/iterate/clear/etc.
}
```

In addition to this manual (or older-school way) there are concurrent objects available in .NET 4 which do basically this but with some other special checks. For the most part these objects are as optimized for performance as you can get for fully-safe objects. If you're using a very controlled and small set of actions on the object (you have 1 add, 1 remove method and never enumerating the whole collection but just accessing specific, known entries) you could use the lighter-weight `lock()` example above to get better performance.

You'll see this especially when adding multiple objects to a collection at once. Using the concurrent objects each Add operation is atomic with locking and unlocking. If you run this in a tight loop you lose a bit of performance to acquiring locks over and over. If another thread is trying to read, the contention for access gets a bit higher. If you use the lock statement yourself, you can just acquire the lock, add the objects in a fast, tight loop and then release the lock. Threads wanting to access the object will wait a little longer but overall the operations should finish faster. Also keep in mind the differences are typically so low it's not really worth it and would fall under the category of premature optimization in almost all cases.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably make it read-only unless you'll ever need to change the value of the variable, yes.

If you're using .NET 4, you should consider using [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) - otherwise, I'd probably write accessors which simply acquire a lock for each access. While you *could* use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` etc, I'd personally go with the simplest safe approach to start with.

Note that iterating over the contents of the dictionary in a thread-safe way will be tricky - hopefully you don't need that though.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Please could you expand on what you mean by "simplest safe approach" so I have an idea of how I would go about implementing this in a Net 35 application as well.

Comment: @SBlackler: The simplest way is just to lock on each access. Will edit with an example.

Comment: @SBlackler: Actually, I've just noticed that the value is a list... that won't be thread-safe *either*. How are you intending to use this? Once populated, would the list be read-only?

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the list not being thread safe either. I'll re-edit with example usage as I am confusing my self here...

Comment: @Jon Good point - the collection contains collections. There is a lot of opportunity to collide.

Comment: Updated with how I am going to use the property. It will always be a `private` declaration if that makes any difference.

Comment: @SBlackler: Well, you've shown that you'd add a `new List<PropertyInfo>` - but what would you do with that list? You need to be safe in terms of how you'll add to that as well

Comment: Marking it private just means only your code in the class is doing any work with the collection. It still doesn't inherently protect the collection from cross-thread access, it just reduces the surface area of potential trouble. And this is void if one of your methods returns the collection to the caller or you have a property access wrapped around it giving up access.

Comment: @ErikNoren, Ok thanks. To make sure I understood correctly, if I am going to declare this as `private static`, I will need to implement a locking mechanism such as you have done in the blog post (remembering that I will only need `Add/Remove`) for Net35 apps and use `private static ConcurrentDictionary` for Net 4+ apps?

Comment: @SBlackler: Even ConcurrentDictionary isn't going to help you much when you've got a mutable type as the value...

Comment: @SBlackler Yes. But not just for static members. This also applies if you're doing event-based programming. This is why there is so much work put into specialized objects to handle, for instance, updating a UI element from an event handler. UI changes can only come from the UI thread to prevent cross-thread issues. BackgroundWorker, DispatherThread, and others are ways to automatically perform synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is in no way thread safe. If multiple threads can insert or remove items at the same time, you have a potential problem.